# Using variable with query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field name authorisation having length 150 chars.

I want query to check authorisation at particular digit.

```
SELECT e.staffid, COUNT(e.staffid) FROM enrll e INNER JOIN staff s on e.staffid=s.staffid 
                        WHERE s.auth = '1' and NOT EXISTS (SELECT staffid FROM shdl h where s.staffid=h.staffid and h.shdldt='$unixdt')
                        GROUP BY e.staffid ORDER BY COUNT(e.staffid) DESC";
```

THough I have used a `"1"` for testing purpose but now I want to check auth at particular digit like.
for that  I took variable with 150 digit. I need to check at 150th position that if  at last position it is 1 it will fetch record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... WHERE SUBSTRING(s.auth,150,1) = '1' ...
```

[`SUBSTRING(str, pos, len)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) can be used for this, but all your index on `s.auth` is useless then.

Comment: Substring is not a sql function than how can I use it with above code. Can you please rewrite the code.

Comment: Substring is a MySQL function, just replace your `WHERE s.auth = '1'` with the code in my answer.

Comment: OK.. what will happen if I use negative value like  `substr(s.auth,-1) = '1'`

Comment: -1 means get the last char, 150 just means get the 150th char. They are equivalent, if you have fixed size of 150 chars.

Comment: But if not you will get empty string.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try

```
substr(s.auth,-1) = '1'
```

Comment: You can check working via query select substr('Testing',-1); Result is g.